# Regression test suit on Jenkins throws several error while same thing on my local is running fine

Tags: selenium, jenkins, automation, regression

My team is using Jenkins for running test suits and getting report. Our regression test suit runs well on local machines while running the same test on Jenkins throws several errors, most of which, nearly 99%, is about selenium unable to locate element. 
What would be cause of the issue?

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[data-testid='regular-shipment-form-step-shipment-scale-button-proceed']"}
>     (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.106)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540471 (9c759b81a907e70363c6312294d30b6ccccc2752),platform=Linux 4.15.0-1077-azure x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the error message and stack trace of one of the failures. You will also need to include some of the test code, so we can see a [repro]. I would just take one of the errors and focus your question on that. Most likely it is a race condition between selenium and the browser, but we cannot help you with the information you have provided.